# Products of o-aminobenzaldehyde thermal treatment with acetone and further with sulfuric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry

> *o*-Aminobenzaldehyde is heated along with acetone in dilute $\ce{NaOH}$ solution to produce the major organic product (**A**), which on treatment with a catalytic amount of $\ce{H2SO4},$ produces another major organic product (**B**) formed via intramolecular reaction.
>
> What will be the products **A** and **B** formed in this reaction?

I have tried solving it and I think **A** will be *o*-aminobenzoic acid. But I want to ask that what happens when *o*-aminobenzoic acid is reacted with catalytic amount of $\ce{H2SO4}?$

Comment: Why do you think A is a benzoic acid? What oxidant is present?

Comment: Do you ever heard of aldol condensation?

Answer (score 8):

This is an example of the Friedländer synthesis of quinolines [Wikipedia article  here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedl%C3%A4nder_synthesis).

Under catalysis by hydroxide acetone undergoes an aldol condensation with the aldehyde group to give **3**, which is your compound **A** ($\ce{R2=Me, R3=H}$). Under the catalysis of sulfuric acid **A** loses water to give the quinoline **7** (for your **B** $\ce{R2 = Me, R3=H}$).

Several reviews of the Friedländer exist, this is a good one [Chem. rev. here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/cr800482c).

[image: Friedländer Reaction]

Image is from [ref 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedl%C3%A4nder_synthesis).

Comment: Which software do you generally use for making the structures?

Comment: this diagram was lifted from the Wikipedia entry. For drawing I resort to Chem Doodle https://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/2d-sketcher/  It's free but not as good as the packages I'm used to.